# How to attach tagify after ajax complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, tags

I am trying to attach `tagify` to an input field which comes back with an ajax request.
I am currently experimenting with this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
        var input = document.getElementById("Tags");
        var tagify = new Tagify(input, { whitelist: [test,test1,test2] });
        var controller;
    });
});
```

However, this results in the warning `Tagify: input element is already Tagified`, as well as some strange behavior:

- The tagified input field `Tags` is still visible
- The `<tags></tags>` tag which is generated by Tagify appears as well but is a lot smaller above the still visible input field
- When I start typing one of the whitelisted tags within the small `<tags>` field, the dropdown list ist displayed at the bottom right

This behavior only happens when I have my code within `$(document).ajaxComplete(function () { //code here });`. If I render a `Tagify` instance within `$(document).ready(function () {});` only, `Tagify` works just great.

Any ideas what I should be doing different so Tagify work correctly after `ajaxComplete`?

What can I try

Comment: Never used that script but docs have lots of methods like destroy, removeAllTags, addtags etc

Comment: *`input element is already Tagified`* says it all no?  this code is running on every ajax request completed I believe and it should only be initialised once (per input)

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var inputElm = $('input[name="product_service"]');
    var tagifyInstance = null; // Variable to store the Tagify instance

    function tagTemplate(tagData) {
        // Template code here
    }

    function suggestionItemTemplate(tagData) {
        // Template code here
    }

    $('#professional_type_id').on('click', function(e) {
        var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
        var valueSelected = this.value;
        $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: "/getProductService", // Replace with the actual URL for the AJAX request
            data: {
                id: valueSelected
            }
        })
        .done(function(result) {
            if (tagifyInstance) {
                // If the input element is already Tagified, destroy the previous instance
                tagifyInstance.destroy();
            }

            // Initialize Tagify on the input node reference
            tagifyInstance = new Tagify(inputElm.get(0), {
                tagTextProp: 'name',
                // Other options and templates
            });

            tagifyInstance.whitelist = result; // Update the whitelist

            // Refresh the Tagify instance
            tagifyInstance.refresh();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your code to make it helpful for other users. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer